# How do I center <img /> <h1>...</h1> <img /> HTML + CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, center

this is frustrating me... I'm trying to make something that looks like this:

```
   Logo

img|h1|img
```

The images that surround the subtitle are just horizontal lines to look like this

--- Subtitle ---

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
     <a href="#">
     <img class="logo" src="#" alt="..."/></a>
 </div>
 <div class="subtitle">
     <img class="1" src="#" width="60" height="1" alt="..."/>
     <h1>subtitle text</h1>
     <img class="2" src="#" width="60" height="1" alt="..."/>
 </div>
```

I've tried placing the elements within another div and defining a width: %; for that div with a margin:0 auto; but the problem with that is that if a user increases their text size within the browser the right image moves to the next line.

Any help would be great. thank you!

Comment: There's many ways to do this. Look into `float:left`, `display:table-cell`, `column-count`, and/or `display:inline-block` (they all have pros and cons, and the best solution depends on various parameters).

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question to get rid of all those pipes, and replace them with a pre block?

Comment: Sure, sorry this is the first time I've used this site :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the inline img tags within the block h1 element then styling the H1 tag as follows:

CSS:

```
h1{
 width: 100px; /* whatever width you prefer*/
 text-align: center;
}
```

Html:

```
 <h1>
    <img class="1" src="#" width="60" height="1" alt="..."/>
    subtitle text
    <img class="2" src="#" width="60" height="1" alt="..."/>
 </h1>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sujvM/  Note*: For some reason you need to click the run button for images to load in jsfiddle.

Comment: Placing the img tags within the h1 element worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  This works because H1 is a block level element, while the img tags are inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline` and `white-space: nowrap` to accomplish this:

```
.subtitle {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.subtitle h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```